# Generate a column AFTER group by?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to use a generated column, but to specify that it should be generated AFTER a group by happens?

I have a series of tables which I join and sum their columns. This works for any columns which are not derived (i.e. not generated) but for columns which are generated I need to take a weighted average after the group by, rather than sum.

Rather than taking a weighted average it would be simpler if I could specify that the generated column should take place after the rows are grouped and summed.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Apologies, here is an edit for more information:

An example generated column is:

```
ALTER TABLE example_table ADD COLUMN
example_generated_column DECIMAL(4, 1) 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (numerator_column / denominator_column * 100) STORED;
```

If I am joining many tables that have a `numerator_column` and `denominator_column` I want these values to be summed before the new column is generated.

Comment: You might want to reword your title and question as from Postgres 12+ there are actual generated columns you can define for a table, see [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html).  I think you are not talking about those, but it is not entirely clear.

Comment: Apologies, I've edited the question. To be clear I am talking about generated columns in postgres 12+.

Comment: You can't do this a generated column can only refer to non-generated columns in its own table. Best bet is to create a view over the join query.

Comment: A generated column can only refer to other values **in the same row**. You cannot, and should not, try to aggregate multiple rows in there.

Answer (score -1):

That kind of calculation doesn't work in a generated column definition, which is actually maybe a good thing since allowing it would invite all kinds of mixed grain anti-pattern tables. What you could do, and what is pretty common in practice, is to build the calculation into a view (or a materialized view, depending on the situation). That will preserve the grain of the base table and still let you get the aggregation you're after.

```
CREATE VIEW schema.table AS
SELECT
  A.col1 AS column1_name,
  A.col2 AS column2_name,
  SUM(A.col3) AS agg_column_name
FROM (
  SELECT
    x AS col1,
    y AS col2,
    COUNT(z) AS col3
  FROM
    some_table
  WHERE
    x = '2023-04-02'
  GROUP BY
    x,
    y
  ) A
GROUP BY
  A.col1,
  A.col2
;
```

I use this type of query often with several `UNION ALL` operations done in the inner query. That allows a pattern like this:

```
SELECT
  A.event_date,
  A.some_attribute,
  SUM(A.new_transaction_count) AS new_transactions,
  SUM(A.old_transaction_count) AS old_transactions
FROM (
  SELECT
    x AS event_date,
    y AS some_attribute,
    COUNT(z) AS new_transaction_count,
    0 AS old_transaction_count
  FROM
    new_data_table
  WHERE
    x = '2023-04-02'
  GROUP BY
    x,
    y

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    x AS event_date,
    y AS some_attribute,
    0 new_transaction_count,
    COUNT(z) AS old_transaction_count
  FROM
    old_data_table
  WHERE
    x = '2023-04-02'
  GROUP BY
    x,
    y
  ) A
GROUP BY
  A.event_date,
  A.some_attribute
;
```

it will give output like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| event_date | some_attribute | new_transactions | old_transactions |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2023-04-02 | foobar         | 1000             | 2000             |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This allows the `SUM` to be applied to the values that were `COUNT`'ed in the inner queries, and the outer `GROUP BY` will flatten the result into a single row.

Comment: Readability might be improved by using the `WITH` clause instead of inline subqueries. Although both approaches are semantically equivalent, there can be execution and performance differences. `WITH` queries might create optimization fences; however, the `NOT MATERIALIZED` option can be used to address this concern (see [SELECT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-select.html)).

Comment: @JohnH CTE's tend to be frowned upon by a lot of the DBA's that I've worked with, although I've met many analysts and data scientists that strongly prefer that style and consider it more readable. Traditional wisdom says that CTE's are performance killers, but IME that is generally not true; most modern optimizers no longer treat a CTE as a way to coerce a specific type of query plan, and will often generate the same or similar explain plans for queries that use either style to describe the same dataset.

Comment: The bigger issue is that this does not address what the OP is asking for, defining a generated column in a table definition.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Sure it does. This can't be done as a generated column, which is probably good since that just invites weird mixed-grain tables and poor data modeling practices. OP can use exactly what is described here in a materialized view that is triggered to refresh by updates on the underlying base table.

Comment: The OP wanted a `GENERATED ALWAYS AS  ...` solution and you gave them something else and presented it as an answer to their specific question. Either make it clear that you are not presenting  an answer for a generated column or change the answer to one that does or delete the answer.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver ok, i updated it, hopefully that is clarifies that this is a possible solution to the problem and not just a "no, sorry, can't do it" answer.